# Best practice for support check of REST methods

Tags: c#, api, rest, versions

First of all, I am aware of this question: 
[Best Practices and How to support different versions of REST APIs in C# wrapper on client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676770/best-practices-and-how-to-support-different-versions-of-rest-apis-in-c-sharp-wra)
but i think my problem is a bit different.

We have a piece of software which can be remote controlled via a REST Api. 
The users will get an update ~twice a year. 
Every update will provide them with some new functionality.

Now we also have a REST client, which is developed in parallel but has different release dates. The client has to support the old versions in addition to the new ones.

The question is now, that i want to know how to build the version check in my REST client code. It is a bit of a luxury design problem...

```
 public void apiStuff(Data input)
 {
     if (api.Versions < "2.5.3")
         throw new Exception("Not supported, please update")

     doApiStuffWith(input);
 }
```

or should I put the *check and throw* part in a private method.

```
 public void apiStuff(Data input)
 {
     checkForVersionSupport("2.5.3");

     doApiStuffWith(input);
 }
```

I think the first approach is more readable as the second one, but it is also redundant code.

Or does anybody have completely different ideas?

Comment: So you're checking your server's API version? That doesn't make sense to me. Also the choice you're making really does not make a difference too much, obviously extracting the functionality to another function is better. Though I'd use some sort of a hook instead of calling this in every api call.

Comment: MS uses V2. You can try Code Contracts too. That said, your question is opinion based.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**
Adjusting for "every method needs different api version" solution.

Abstract client logic to an interface:

```
public interface IApiClient
{
    void Foo();
    int GetCurrentVersion();
}
```

Make an attribute to method-by-method API version:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class ApiVersionRangeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int MinVersion { get; private set; }
    public int MaxVersion { get; private set; }
    public ApiVersionRangeAttribute(int minVersion, int maxVersion)
    {
        MinVersion = minVersion;
        MaxVersion = maxVersion;
    }

    public void Validate(int version)
    {
        if (version < MinVersion || version > MaxVersion)
        {
            throw new Exception("Upgrade");
        }
    }
}
```

And create a factory that will take that attribute into an account:

```
//nuget: Install-Package Castle.Core
using System;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
public class ApiClientFactory
{
    public class ApiClient : IApiClient
    {
        [ApiVersionRange(10, 20)]
        public void Foo()
        {
            Console.Write("Foo");
        }
        public int GetCurrentVersion()
        {
            // call to the server here instead :)
            return 50;
        }
    }

    public IApiClient CreateClient()
    {
        var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        var apiClient = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<IApiClient>(
          new ApiClient(), new VersionInterceptor());
        return apiClient;
    }
}

public class VersionInterceptor : StandardInterceptor
{
    protected override void PreProceed(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var attributes = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget.GetCustomAttributes(
          typeof(ApiVersionRangeAttribute), false);
        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length == 1)
        {
            var apiRange = (ApiVersionRangeAttribute)attributes[0];
            var proxy = (IApiClient)invocation.Proxy;
            apiRange.Validate(proxy.GetCurrentVersion());
        }
        base.PreProceed(invocation);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
 var apiClient = new ApiClientFactory().CreateClient();
 // fail - 50 is not in range 10-20
 apiClient.Foo();
```

Comment: So i should build a new client for every single version and check the version at instantiating?
It is to much overhead for my case. There are to much diferent versions.

Comment: This solution would avoid the possibility to use an old client version with a new server version. This wouldn't fit the requirements.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but i WANT the user to get a message that he has to update.
So he is forced to update his server if he "sees" the functions wich he can't use.

Comment: @Alu - see my update; I haven't realized (it is not written in the question) that you have zillion of versions & one api client instance that check version on method-per-method bias.

Comment: How about using `Version` instead of `int`

Comment: Nice solution
But i think its wayyy to complicated. I wanted to avoid code duplication/complexity with my question  ;)

I think i use my first approach with an constant variable to specify the error message. It is the most readable solution and not so much code overhead.

Answer (score 1):

> IMHO consider `Version` instead of `int` and use the `AttributeUsage` for redundancy.
>
> The above answer has depicted the usage of attributes

```
public void CheckVersion(Version currentVersion)
{
   //Get your version from assembly 
    Version applicationVersion = new Version(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyFileVersion);

   //
  if (currentVersion.CompareTo(applicationVersion) == 1)
      throw your Exception("Not supported");
}
```